# How to get user language settings in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is it possible to retrieve the language setting of a user inside Teams using the Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the desktop client setting? Isn't it just an application setting (not synchronized with the cloud)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such specific API for teams language ,you can use PATCH method to update a subset of the properties of a user's regional and language settings https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/settings/regionalandlanguagesettings
Content-type: application/json

Please see the docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/regionalandlanguagesettings-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would affect the user's M365 server-side settings, but I don't know that this relates at all to the selected language in the Team's client itself (note on the screenshot in OP it refers to 'App language').

Comment: Oh Ok, which i already mentioned in my answer that there is no such API for teams ,Thanks.